# How Can I Improve Colour Reproduction When Styling HERE Maps?

Tags: android, colors, here-api

When styling a HERE Map for an application using the NORMAL_DAY scheme as a base, I have noticed that the colours of some map elements are exactly as assigned, while others are off by 2-4% (the amount of black in the colour) and some others are wildly off (30-40%).

For example, LAND was sampled at ARGB 255,251,57,57 while it was *actually* set to ARGB 255,255,0,0 (pure red).  It feels like there is some kind of runtime manipulation of assigned colour values.

Can anyone shed light on this? How can this be compensated for?

Comment: I set an area on the map to be jet black (ARGB 255, 0, 0, 0) and values sampled from a screenshot measured ARGB 255, 54, 55, 56.

Answer (score 0):

you can load the custom style. please refer https://heremaps.github.io/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/change-style-at-load/data/dark.yaml

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  This applies to the Android Premium SDK, not the JavaScript API